# If I can't use aggregate in a where clause, how to get results

Tags: postgresql

Ok I have a query where I need to ommit the result if the first value of an array_agg = natural so I thought I can do this:

```
select
  visitor_id,
  array_agg(code
   order by session_start) codes_array
from mark_conversion_sessions
where conv_visit_num2 < 2
  and max_conv = 1
  and (array_agg(code
    order by session_start))[1] != 'natural'
group by visitor_id
```

But when I run this I get the error:

```
ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 31: and (array_agg(code
```

So is there a way I can reference that array_agg in the where clause?

Thank you

Comment: Use `having` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP

Comment: try using group by and having clauses. http://www.dofactory.com/sql/having

Comment: Where filters rows,having filters groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `having` clause is used to act like a `where` clause on grouped data.   Move the criteria that is using aggregates into the having clause, eg:

```
select
  visitor_id,
  array_agg(code order by session_start) codes_array
from mark_conversion_sessions
where 
  conv_visit_num2 < 2
  and max_conv = 1
group by visitor_id
having
    (array_agg(code order by session_start))[1] != 'natural'
```

docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-agg.html

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you!